# Searching for up and down arrow symbol (⇅)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, arrows

Whats the command for this symbol: ⇅

I've found ⇈ `\upuparrows` but I can't find the other one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol). Try to search for `\updownarrows`

Answer (score 14):

The package `mathabx` provides all arrows of this kind. The one you're looking for is `\updownarrows`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

$\upuparrows$ -  $\downdownarrows$ - $\updownarrows$ - $\downuparrows$

\end{document}
```

[image]

For such questions, a good place to look at is [the comprehensive LaTeX symbols list](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Note that `mathabx` redefines *many* symbols. An alternative is the following code, which produces updownarrows in a pure-latex fashion, but as you can see, the result is still not fully identical to `amssymb`'s `\upuparrows`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\updownarrows}{\mathbin\uparrow\hspace{-.5em}\downarrow}
\newcommand{\downuparrows}{\mathbin\downarrow\hspace{-.5em}\uparrow}

\begin{document}

$\upuparrows$ -  $\downdownarrows$ - $\updownarrows$ - $\downuparrows$


\end{document}
```

[image]

A possible solution would be to redefine `\upuparrows` and `\downdownarrows` as well :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\updownarrows}{\mathbin\uparrow\hspace{-.3em}\downarrow}
\newcommand{\downuparrows}{\mathbin\downarrow\hspace{-.3em}\uparrow}
\renewcommand{\upuparrows}{\mathbin\uparrow\hspace{-.3em}\uparrow}
\renewcommand{\downdownarrows}{\mathbin\downarrow\hspace{-.3em}\downarrow}

\begin{document}

$\upuparrows$ -  $\downdownarrows$ - $\updownarrows$ - $\downuparrows$

\end{document}
```

[image]

In comments, egreg proposed the following answer, for the same result (well, not technically the same), but with a cleaner code. It will probably give better spacing results if used within longer formulas :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\updownarrows}{\uparrow\mathrel{\mspace{-1mu}}\downarrow}
\newcommand{\downuparrows}{\downarrow\mathrel{\mspace{-1mu}}\uparrow}
\renewcommand{\upuparrows}{\uparrow\uparrow}
\renewcommand{\downdownarrows}{\downarrow\downarrow}

\begin{document}

$\upuparrows$ -  $\downdownarrows$ - $\updownarrows$ - $\downuparrows$

\end{document}
```

[image: tex output]

Comment: Usual caveat: `mathabx` changes *many* symbols with its owns.

Comment: @egreg : Indeed, and even those arrows don't have the same heads as the usual arrows. I will edit with a pure-latex solution, but the result isn't exactly similar to amssymb's double arrows either.

Comment: Why those `\mathbin` tokens in the last solution? They act only on the following token and affect the global spacing.

Comment: @egreg : If I don't add them, the arrows will be stuck to the dash, unlike the regular `\upuparrows`. About the command affecting only the first token, that's what I thought as well, but since the result seems quite symmetrically spaced, I did not change it further.

Comment: I'd simply go for `\uparrow\uparrow` and `\uparrow\mathrel{\mspace{-1mu}}\downarrow`, using the fact that those arrows are defined as relation symbols.

Answer (score 3):

`\updownarrows` is present in the Unicode table and it is included in typical Unicode math fonts. For example with OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[lm]

The $\updownarrows$ is the same as $⇅$.

\bye
```

General rule: When you are able to write down the desired character in the question form here (and we see it here in title too), then the character is declared in Unicode. You can use a proper Unicode font and simply use the character.

Answer (score 1):

The shape of `\upuparrows` doesn't match with the shape of `\uparrow` in the Computer Modern fonts.

I don't like too much the shape of arrows in the Computer Modern fonts, to be honest: I find that the original versions were far better, with smaller tips.

Here's the visual proof:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\upuparrows \uparrow$

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you load `old-arrows`, then magically all arrows become the same as in `amssymb` (that was designed when the CM arrows had smaller tips):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{old-arrows}

\begin{document}

$\upuparrows \uparrow$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now defining `\updownarrows` and `\downuparrows` is a breeze:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{old-arrows}

\newcommand{\updownarrows}{\uparrow\joinrel\downarrow}
\newcommand{\downuparrows}{\downarrow\joinrel\uparrow}

\begin{document}

$\uparrow \downarrow \upuparrows \downdownarrows \updownarrows \downuparrows$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might prefer the arrows to be even nearer to each other. With

```
\newcommand{\updownarrows}{\uparrow\mathrel{\mspace{-4mu}}\downarrow}
\newcommand{\downuparrows}{\downarrow\mathrel{\mspace{-4mu}}\uparrow}
```

the same input as above would produce

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to rotate \rightleftarrows by 90 degrees using \rotatebox from graphicx. It produces an \updownarrows that is visually compatible with \upuparrows.

```
\newcommand{\updownarrows}{\mathrel{\kern1pt\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\rightleftarrows$}\kern-1pt}}
```

(This requires the graphicx package)

[image: The result in context, with \upuparrows also shown]

Comment: A legitimate solution. However, in order to be appreciated (i.e. upvoted) you should expand it to a complete code, maybe with a snapshot of the result.