# LaTeX symbol for table sorting

Tags: symbols

I was wandering if there was some symbol that I could use in my tables, to give some visual information about which column is being used for ordering. By this, I mean those little triangles that are used pretty much everywhere when sorting via a column is involved, both up and down.

Thanks.

Comment: \usepackage{wasysym} with `\DOWNarrow` and `\UParrow`. related [Searching for up and down arrow symbol (⇅)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86238/15717). Lazyguy like me uses http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: Very nice question.  I'm wondering whether an hour will be enough for a tikz answer to appear;)...  Meanwhile, let me suggest `\vartriangle`/`\triangledown` or `\blacktriangle`/`\blacktriangledown` from `amssymb`.

Comment: @texenthusiast very nice suggestion the detexify, bookmarked already!

Comment: I end up going for the `\blactriangledown` and `\blacktriangle` from `amssymb`. Consider writing up in an answer so that it can be accepted. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome. if you include @mbork in your comment you can communicate with him directly to make his suggestion as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After consulting the [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), here is what I found (notice that in case of gray icons, you will need the `color` or `xcolor` package):

[image: A comparison of triangle icons suitable for denoting sorting order]

If none of the above suits you, you might want to look up https://www.google.com/search?q=sorting+icons or attempt a custom TikZ solution.

Edit: as user @texenthusiast pointed out, there is one more useful resource - [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), where you draw a symbol and get a LaTeX command to obtain it.

Comment: if you don't mind can you include the detexify link as the [OP liked it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102543/latex-symbol-for-table-sorting#comment223594_102543) and useful for future users

Comment: Good point, @texenthusiast!  Done.